# Mysql 5.7 Left join orderBy average not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

This is my query:

```
SELECT AVG(user_reviews.rate) AS SQLAVG,facilities_stores.* 
FROM `facilities_stores` 
LEFT JOIN user_reviews ON user_reviews.facility_id = facilities_stores.id 
WHERE facilities_stores.id IN (17,20,21,35) 
GROUP BY facilities_stores.id ORDER BY SQLAVG DESC
```

If this is SUM or COUNT. This query working fine.

But when it is AVG not work.

This query working fine with Mysql < 5.6. I'm not sure what I'm wrong.

Look like at Mysql 5.7 have conflict of `ORDER BY` with `GROUP BY`

This is my result

[image]

Comment: what is your expected result? without sample data your result doesnt tell us anything. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You seem to have an incomplete `GROUP BY` clause, something that MySQL is too tolerant for by default. Most likely, your results in MySQL/5.6 where incorrect too, or they were correct by pure chance.

Comment: @e4c5 I had try this but I got result is Null.

Comment: If the links in the close don't make sense let us know. @e4c5 recommended one that had an answer from Ollie. The other one had answers from Shadow and myself.